# Can I use SQP(Sequential quadratic programming) in scipy for neural network regression optimization?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, deep-learning, regression

As title, after training and testing my neural network model in python.

Can I use SQP function in `scipy` for neural network regression problem optimization?

For example, I am using temperature,humid,wind speed ,these three feature for input,predicting energy usage in some area.

So I use neural network to model these input and output's relationship, now I wanna know some energy usage lowest point, what input feature are(i.e. what temperature,humid,wind seed are).This just example so may sound unrealistic.

Because as far as I know, not so many people just use `scipy` for neural network optimization. But in some limitation , `scipy`  is the most ideal optimization tool what I have by now(p.s.: I can't use `cvxopt`).

Can someone give me some advice? I will be very appreciate!

Comment: Quadratic programming is not even applicable in this case, as the loss surface is not convex.

Comment: But I have seen some papers about NN optimization problem using sqp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that's possible, but your question is too broad to give a complete answer as all details are missing.

**But: SLSQP is not the right tool!**

- There is a reason, **NN training is dominated by first-order methods** like SGD and all it's variants

  - Fast calculation of gradients and easy to do in mini-batch mode (not paying for the full gradient; less memory)
  - Very different convergence theory for Stochastic-Gradient-Descent which is usually much better for large-scale problems
  - In general: fast iteration speed (e.g. time per epoch) while possibly needing more epochs (for full convergence)
- NN is unconstrained continuous optimization

  - SLSQP is a very general optimization able to tackle constraints and you will pay for that (performance and robustness)
  - LBFGS is actually the only tool (which i saw) sometimes used to do that (and also available in scipy)

    - It's a bound-constrained optimizer (no general constraints as SLSQP)
    - It approximates the inverse-hessian and therefore memory-usage is greatly reduced compared to BFGS and also SLSQP
  - Both methods are full-batch methods (opposed to the online/minibatch nature of **S**GD

    - They are also using Line-searches or something similar which results less hyper-parameters to tune: no learning-rates!

I think you should stick to SGD and it's variants.

If you want to go for the second-order approach: [learn from sklearn's implementation using LBFGS](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier)

Comment: In my opinion, NN's training using like SGD, it's fitting input and output's data pattern. But as I mention above,for example,now I already using temperature,humid,wind speed ,these feature for input to training NN for predicting energy usage,i.e. modeling these input and output's relationship and I use SGD to train,  Now I wanna know some energy usage lowest point, i.e. what input circumstances are(i.e. what temperature,humid,wind), can make this area's energy's usage in the lowest point. So maybe this problem is another optimization problem? Can you clarify my question?  Thanks!!!